# python ordered_dict from json

Tags: json, python-2.6, ordereddictionary

I am using Python 2.6.6, and trying to generate a ordered_dict from json string. I could understand that I could use object_pairs_hook of json Decoder/loads, but unfortunately it's not supported in 2.6.6. Is there any way out?

```
e.g. 
template_s = '{ "aa": {"_type": "T1"}, "bb": {"_type": "T11"}}'
json.loads(template_s, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
>>> json.loads(json_str, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
  return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object_pairs_hook'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do the same with simplejson

```
import simplejson as json
json.loads(config_str, object_pairs_hook=json.OrderedDict)
```